# How to find group wise total(Sum) in SAP crystal report?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports, c#-3.0

How to find group wise total(Sum) in SAP crystal report?

Dear All,

I have to find the Sum of value based on the Date(01/01/2014……) And Regional (North,West,East,Central) wise….But 2014,2013 column data type varchar(25)
Here I will give little Example of what I want to do:

```
Date                  Regional      StationName         2014               2013

01/01/14               North        AAA                  1000.00          100.20

01/01/14               North        BBB                   500.00           50.00     

                  1500.00 150.2


01/01/14               West     ZZZ                100.00   00.00

01/01/14               West     YYY             500.00  10.00    

                  600.00   10.00

     Grand Total :2100.00  160.2
```

Comment: you are answering the question in your brief, first you have to convert the varchar date to datetime format in your database. you can then change the display format from the report

Answer (score 0):

to get that done you will have to create 2 groups, one by `Date`(suppressed) and another by `Regional` where you are going to place all of your fields. Then crate to formulas, one for 2014 and another for 2013 columns to convert those strings to number using `tonumber()` function. For example `tonumber(2014)`. Then you will have to summarize 2014 and 2013 based on `Regional Group` and `grand totals` for both as well.

Comment: Dear Cojimarmiami...     Thanks for your valuable sugg.... Actually i need only Regional[not Date wise] wise summary.So, Please tell me exact formula and how to convert...

Comment: My Team viewer id is 676 398 263 so if you want access my report please you can do it.....

Comment: @KarthikRamasamy need your teamv password as well